# start adb server in wireless mode without connecting actual device via usb

Tags: android, adb, wifi

sometimes, I forget to carry USB cable and need to connect android phone over wifi to use adb!! But the problem is adb can't be started in tcpip mode without connecting phone via USB!! what should I do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you either need to have a device connected or an running emulator for using following command:

adb tcpip 5555

what if you don't have usb cable for some reason? what to do? here's a solution. If you run an android emulator, above command will work but draw back is , it take too much time (few minutes to be specific). So what's the fastest solution,

Well, install AnBox. Its also an emulator which opens much faster, within few seconds. now, you can run above command:

adb tcpip 5555

to start adb in tcpip mode

use below command to connect to your android phone over wifi

adb connect :5555